# Use SSE intrinsics for 2D arrays in C

Tags: c, sse, intrinsics

I want to use SSE to optimize this code:

```
v[0][0] = 2*vi-v[1][0];
for (j=1;j<=jmax;j++) {
    u[0][j] = ui;
    v[0][j] = 2*vi-v[1][j];
}
```

What I did so far is this:

```
v[0][0] = 2*vi-v[1][0];
for (j=1;j<=jmax;j++) {
    __m128 uiVec = _mm_set1_ps(ui);
    __m128 viVec = _mm_set1_ps(vi);
    __m128 constant = _mm_set1_ps(2);

    __m128 v1Vec = _mm_load_ps(v[1]+j);

    _mm_store_ps(v[0]+j, uiVec);

    __m128 v0Calc = _mm_mul_ps(constant, viVec);
    __m128 v0Result = _mm_sub_ps(v0Calc, v1Vec);

    _mm_store_ps(v[0]+j, v0Result);
}
```

But I get a segmentation fault. When I checked the code the problem is within the *_mm_store_ps* function.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Are your arrays aligned by 16?  Is every row each aligned by 16?  `_mm_store_ps` requires 16-byte alignment.  Use `loadu` / `storeu` if you need to.

Comment: whenever you use intrinsics you can force the aligment with gcc using attributes: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Type-Attributes.html

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL: Why are you linking ancient GCC 3.3 docs?  Just use C11 `alignas(16) float arr[4][64]` or whatever.  (`#include <stdalign.h>` for alignas(), otherwise use `_Alignas`).  That's a portable version of what GNUC `__attribute__((aligned(16)))` can do.